# How to call ajax from service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, promise, angular-promise

I have Employee controller which is having property Id, Name , Specification. I have made one Employee service which is having ajax call and get employee list. But every time getting '' in User.
When i debug the code i found that it call success first and then it goes for Ajax call.
When i do ajax call without service it works fine.

```
 angular.module('EmployeeServiceModule', [])
.service('EmployeeSer', ['$http',function ($http) {
    this.Users = '';
    this.errors = '';
    this.SearchEmployee = function () {
 // Ajax call
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Home/GetEmployeeList',
            params: { filterData: 'Test' },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(onSuccess, onError);

        var onSuccess = function (response) {
            this.userUsers = response.data;
            this.errors = '';
        };

        var onError = function (reason) {
            this.userUsers = reason;
            this.errors = "Error in retrieving data.";
        };

        return this.Users;
    }   
}]);


angular.module('Employee', ['EmployeeServiceModule'])
.controller('EmployeeController', ['EmployeeSer', '$scope', '$http', function (EmployeeSer, $scope, $http) {

    this.Id = '';
    this.name = '';
    this.expertise = '';
    $scope.repoSortOrder = 'id';
    $scope.filterField = '';

    // Call to service
    this.GetAllEmployee = function () {
        // Initiates the AJAX call
        $scope.User = EmployeeSer.SearchEmployee();
        // Returns the promise - Contains result once request completes
        return true;
    };

    this.AddEmployee = function () {
        var empData = {
            Id: $("#txtId").val(),
            Name: $("#txtName").val(),
            Expertise: $("#expertise").val()
        };

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/Create',
            params: JSON.stringify(empData),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(onSuccess, onError);
        // Returns the promise - Contains result once request completes
        return true;
    };

    var onSuccess = function (response) {
        $scope.user = response.data;
        $scope.error = '';
    };

    var onError = function (reason) {
        $scope.error = "Error in retrieving data.";
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are returning the users before the data is fetched from the server. Also it doesn't seem like you are assigning them correctly.

Here are two ways to solve the problem:

Firstly. You bind your controller user-data to the user-data in the service.

```
angular.module('EmployeeServiceModule', [])
      .service('EmployeeSer', ['$http',function ($http) {
          this.Users = '';
          this.errors = '';
          $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: '/Home/GetEmployeeList',
             params: { filterData: 'Test' },
             headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
          }).then(onSuccess, onError);

          var onSuccess = function (response) {
              this.Users = response.data;
              this.errors = '';
          };

         var onError = function (reason) {
              this.users = null;
              this.errors = "Error in retrieving data.";
         };
     }   
}]);


angular.module('Employee', ['EmployeeServiceModule'])
       .controller('EmployeeController', ['EmployeeSer', '$scope', '$http', function (EmployeeSer, $scope, $http) {
           this.users = EmployeeSer.users;
           EmployeeSer.SearchEmployee();
}]);
```

And the second way would be to return the promise in the service and unwrap it in the controller.

```
angular.module('EmployeeServiceModule', [])
       .service('EmployeeSer', ['$http',function ($http) {
          this.SearchEmployee = function () {
               return $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: '/Home/GetEmployeeList',
                  params: { filterData: 'Test' },
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
               });
          }   
}]);


angular.module('Employee', ['EmployeeServiceModule'])
       .controller('EmployeeController', ['EmployeeSer', '$scope', '$http', function (EmployeeSer, $scope, $http) {

       this.GetAllEmployee = function () {
            EmployeeSer.SearchEmployee()
                       .then(onSuccess, onError)
       };

       var onSuccess = function (response) {
            $scope.user = response.data;
            $scope.error = '';
       };

       var onError = function (reason) {
            $scope.error = "Error in retrieving data.";
       };

}]);
```

**OFF TOPIC**
You should probably consider using ngModel instead of jQuery to get you data to the controller.
Not like this:

```
var empData = {
      Id: $("#txtId").val(),
      Name: $("#txtName").val(),
      Expertise: $("#expertise").val()
};
```

Comment: headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } works with data: $('#formid').serialize()

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here serverRequest is my service to make requests to the server

serverRequest.postReq = function(url, data, sucessCallback, errorCallback){
$http({
method: 'POST', 
url: urlToBeUsed, 
data:data,
headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
sucessCallback(data);
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
errorCallback(data);
})
}

// In the controller 
serverRequest.postReq('urlToBeCalled', dataToBeSent, scope.successCb, scope.errorCb);

scope.successCb = function(data){
// functionality to be done
}
scope.errorCb = function(data){
// functionality to be done
}

Try it this way your problem might be solved
Promise must be unwrapped in your controller if you want to use it
```